# How to reload a jQuery plugin when appending new data to window. No reload() method provided

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, spectrum

I'm working on a site where a user can create however many domains he wishes on a server. Each domain can belong to a group(this overall does nothing to the domain itself it's there for easier sorting).

A user can add/delete/modify each group separately.

I'm using a jQuery plugin called [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) so that a user can assign a color to each of his groups. See [here](http://i.imgur.com/Dlb0Mmy.jpg).

I'm doing some ajax to dynamically update the groups(change the color/name). Everything is working great, except for one thing: the above mentioned plugin doesn't work properly for appended html(which I suppose is to be expected).

Normally for such a thing I'd reload the plugin, however I don't see any method in the documentation that would allow me to do that.

Is there some other way that I could reload it? Maybe some jQuery method? Bind to some event? Something?

Any help is appreciated.

---

```
function ajaxAddDomainGroup(group_color_add, group_name_add) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "<?= URL::route('domains_ajax_add_group'); ?>",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'data[group_name]=' + group_name_add  + '&data[group_color]=' + group_color_add,
        success: function (data)
        {
            if(data.status == 'OK') {
                $.notify('Group added successfully.', {
                    type: 'info',
                    delay: 120000
                });
                $('#js--groups_table tr:first').before(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td class="ccs-table__label" style="background-color: ' + data.data.group_color + '!important;"' + '>' + data.data.group_name + '</td>' +
                    '   <td class="ccs-table__action js--groups_edit">' +
                    '<a  href="#"><span class="icon-edit-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td class="ccs-table__action"><a id="delete_' + data.data.id + '" class="ccs-groups_delete" href="#"><span class="icon-delete-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a></td>' +
                    '</tr><tr><td colspan="3"><div class="js--edit_info css-hide_edit_info box__controls">' +
                    '<div class="col-md-6"> <input class="input--block js--input_group_name_edit" type="text" placeholder="New group name">' +
                    '</div><div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn--action btn--default js--group_edit btn__text" id="js--edit_' + data.data.id + '" href="#">Modify</a>' +
                    '<input class="js--spectrum-color-edit"/> <input type="hidden" class="js--group_color_edit" value="#000000"/> </div> </div> </td> ' +
                    '</tr>'
                );
            }
            else {
                $.notify('An error has occurred when trying to add the group.', {
                    type: 'info',
                    delay: 120000
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
function ajaxEditDomainGroup(group_name_edit, group_color_edit, group_id_edit) {

$.ajax({
    url: "<?= URL::route('domains_ajax_edit_group'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'data[new_group_name]=' + group_name_edit + '&data[new_group_color]=' + group_color_edit + '&data[group_id]=' + group_id_edit,
    success: function (data)
    {
        if(data.status == 'OK') {
            $.notify('Group edited successfully.', {
                type: 'info',
                delay: 120000
            });

            $('#js--edit_' + group_id_edit).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:first-child').replaceWith(
            '<td class="ccs-table__label" style="background-color: ' + group_color_edit + '!important;">' + group_name_edit + '</td>'
            );
        }
        else {
            $.notify('An error has occurred when trying to edit the group.', {
                type: 'info',
                delay: 120000
            });
        }
    }
});
```

}

---

```
$('body').on('click','.js--group_edit', function() {
    var group_name_edit = $(this).closest('td').find('.js--input_group_name_edit').val();
    var group_color_edit = $(this).closest('td').find('.js--group_color_edit').val();
    var group_id_edit = parseInt($(this).attr('id').replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10);

    if($.trim(group_color_edit) == '') {
        alert('The group color is required.');
        return false;
    }
    else if( $.trim(group_name_edit) == '') {
        alert('The group name is required.');
        return false;
    }

    ajaxEditDomainGroup(group_name_edit, group_color_edit, group_id_edit);
});
```

---

Relevant html:

```
@foreach($domain_groups as $key => $domain_info)
    <tr>
        <td class="ccs-table__label"
                @if(isset($domain_info['color']) && $domain_info['color'] != ''))
                    style="background-color: {{ $domain_info['color'] }}!important;"
                @endif
                >{{ $domain_info['group_name']; }}
        </td>
        <td class="ccs-table__action js--groups_edit">
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-edit-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a>
        </td>
        <td class="ccs-table__action"><a id="delete_{{ $domain_info['id'] }}" class="ccs-groups_delete" href="#"><span class="icon-delete-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div class="js--edit_info css-hide_edit_info box__controls">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="input--block js--input_group_name_edit" type="text" placeholder="New group name">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a class="btn btn--action btn--default js--group_edit btn__text" id="js--edit_{{ $domain_info['id'] }}" href="#">Modify</a>
                    <input class="js--spectrum-color-edit"/>
                    <input type="hidden" class="js--group_color_edit" value="#000000"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

---

Spectrum init and such:

```
$(".js--spectrum-color-edit").spectrum({
    color: '#000',
    showAlpha: true,showInput: true,
    // Set the hext value of the color to a hidden input
    move: function(color){
        $(this).closest('td').find('.js--group_color_edit').val(color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

I realize this isn't the most easy-on-the-eyes code. Odds are it's gonna be refactored in the future using angular or something like that.

Comment: The simple case is to apply it to just the loaded elements that match. The complex one is to fix the plugin to work with delegation (sometimes possible). Please show *your* actual code so realistic suggestions can be made :)

Comment: Alrighty, gonna add some code.

Comment: Show us your code ... I believe you don't need to reload the plugin but re-run your code which might look like this: `$("#target").spectrum(...)`

Comment: @leo.fcx Could very well be. I'm not exactly an expert when it comes to js.

Comment: side-note: Use `document` and not `body` for delegated events. `body` has a subtle bug with styling that can cause mouse events not to hit it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Right... -.-. Good to know, I'll switch to document.

Comment: Most of the time it is fine, but `document` has the added advantage of *always existing* so you don't need to put document-delegated events in a DOM ready handler :)

Comment: `js--spectrum-color-main` does not exist in any of the HTML visible. What else might be missing? Can you snapshot the output HTML  from a browser and put it in a JSFiddle to play with?

Comment: My bad, wrong copy+paste. I've removed it and added the right one.

Comment: Suggest added below. Not used Spectrum myself, but the same rules apply to most plugins. Just apply it to the newly added matching items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply spectrum to any newly created *matching* elements within the dynamically loaded rows:

```
var $newtr = $('<tr>' +
               '<td class="ccs-table__label" style="background-color: ' + data.data.group_color + '!important;"' + '>' + data.data.group_name + '</td>' +
               '   <td class="ccs-table__action js--groups_edit">' +
               '<a  href="#"><span class="icon-edit-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a>' +
               '</td>' +
               '<td class="ccs-table__action"><a id="delete_' + data.data.id + '" class="ccs-groups_delete" href="#"><span class="icon-delete-ccs icon-ccs"></span></a></td>' +
               '</tr><tr><td colspan="3"><div class="js--edit_info css-hide_edit_info box__controls">' +
               '<div class="col-md-6"> <input class="input--block js--input_group_name_edit" type="text" placeholder="New group name">' +
               '</div><div class="col-md-6"><a class="btn btn--action btn--default js--group_edit btn__text" id="js--edit_' + data.data.id + '" href="#">Modify</a>' +
               '<input class="js--spectrum-color-edit"/> <input type="hidden" class="js--group_color_edit" value="#000000"/> </div> </div> </td> ' +
               '</tr>');
$('#js--groups_table tr:first').before($newtr)

$(".js--spectrum-color-edit", $newtr).spectrum({
    color: '#000',
    showAlpha: true,
    showInput: true,
    // Set the hext value of the color to a hidden input
    move: function (color) {
        $(this).closest('td').find('.js--group_color_edit').val(color.toHexString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I'll be damned. It was that easy. Can't thank you enough. I've been scratching my head sideways for about 40 minutes now.